# Datatables - Added new row's first column not sorting

Tags: datatables

I have code to add a new row into my datatable and this works fine. The problem is, the first column of the new row won't sort with the other rows if I click the sorting arrows beside the column name. The other rows will sort but the new row will always stay at the bottom of the datatable. This only seems to happen for the first column of the new row. Does anyone have any ideas why?

The first column type is num-html, and I would have values like R1, R2, R3 etc. The hard coded values can be sorted fine but not the dynamically created ones

Comment: can you show column type and some value of it

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using a custom sorting algorithm for the datatable